# Can TeamCity pull from a tag instead of the tip when retrieving files from a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

This is with version 5.0.2 of TeamCity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of TeamCity has added an option in the VCS Root config to specify which branch/tag to pull.

Comment: What exactly do you modify in the VCS Root config to specify a tag to pull? I'm currently getting desperate to find a solution to this which is why i'm commenting on this old post :(

Answer (score 4):

*This question seems pretty dead, but here's what I did (I had to figure it out today):*

**TeamCity** (I'm using 6.0) seems to swallow the '#' symbol in the uri, so you just need to make sure you put it in quotes:

`"https://<username>:<password>@bitbucket.org/<your-account>/<your-project>#<your-release-tag>"`

A few other quircks:

- TeamCity may see the hash and try to populate the **Branch Name** textbox.  Delete anything it puts in here as Hg doesn't *seem* to support this.
- Because the url needs to be in quotes, you need to embed your username/password in the url (anything in the **User name** or **Password** text boxes will be ignored).  TeamCity can't insert them like it normally would because of the quotes around the url.

Comment: It looks like doing ##release-tag will cause it to generate the correct URL, without having to put it in quotes or hardcode your u/p.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with TeamCity, but if it passes the pull path directly to Mercurial, then try adding `#tag` at the end of your URL. That is,

```
hg clone 'https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg#1.2'
```

will clone up to version 1.2 of Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar scenario, wherein we wanted to have a build configuration that would always build whatever was tagged as a production build. I solved the issue by switching checkout mode to "agent checkout" so that the agent working directory contains the entire mercurial repository, not just the latest files. I then added a build step before the actual build. All it does is:

```
hg update prod-build
```

after which the build can proceed on the correct version.

Note that this is on TC 6.5, but I assume custom build steps are in the cards for TC 5 as well.

Comment: I think 7.1 supports for building specific branches. Does anyone tried to use this with Mercurial and Tags